# Can I use Nyancat for my game?

Tags: legal, copyright

I tried to find the information regarding the copyright/ownership of the Nyancat but couldn't find anything concrete.

1. Can I use Nyan as part of the name of my game?
2. Can I use the Nyancat graphics for my game?
3. Can I use the Nyancat sound for my game?

Comment: I think this question is too localized. Voting to close. Plus legal questions aren't a particularly good fit here, talk to a lawyer. And, if you want my opinion, come up with something original, you avoid the hassle of legal issues and it's not some lame internet meme.

Comment: I understand your POV. However, I think we can draw some generalized conclusions by studying this example case of an internet meme.

Comment: The song, video, and artwork are all under copyright. I would advise against using them without proper expressed written permission. It becoming a meme doesn't make it any less someone else's intellectual property.

Comment: Also... after doing the research for my answer, I'd have to say -1 for lack of research, since it was a single Google search.

Answer (score 5):

If you're unsure, you need to research. One search in Google for "nyan cat copyrighted" brings up [this question and answer](http://www.quora.com/Nyan-Cat/Is-the-Nyan-Cat-copyrighted), and [this one](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Is_nyan_cat_copyrighted) and [this one](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111009065203AAP5FYM) and [so on](http://knowyourmeme.com/blog/interviews/qa-with-chris-torres-the-creator-of-nyan-cat). This is the process for any resource you find online, research it before using it.

You can also search the government's database for copyright in the US and [find Nyancat there](http://cocatalog.loc.gov/cgi-bin/Pwebrecon.cgi?Search_Arg=VAu001063390&Search_Code=REGS&PID=M1yKAIB8CJJc_MTQiBEUPCFRpI&SEQ=20130418124439&CNT=25&HIST=1).

To answer you specifically about this meme. Yes it has copyright on everything about it. There's some question about whether the owners of the copyright would pursue you for using it, so that's up to you.